# I want to modify my list input within the class function // Python

Tags: python

I'm new to programming & trying to create a tic-tac-toe board in python. I created an empty board with the following:

```py
class Board(Position):
    state: list[list[int]]

    def __init__(self):
        self.state = [["-", "-", "-"], ["-", "-", "-"], ["-", "-", "-"]]

    def __str__(self):
        board = "  %s  |  %s  |  %s  \n" %(self.state[0][0], self.state[0][1], self.state[0][2])
        board += "_____|_____|_____\n"
        board += "     |     |     \n"
        board += "  %s  |  %s  |  %s  \n" % (self.state[1][0], self.state[1][1], self.state[1][2])
        board += "_____|_____|_____\n"
        board += "     |     |     \n"
        board += "  %s  |  %s  |  %s  \n" % (self.state[2][0], self.state[2][1], self.state[2][2])
        board += "     |     |     \n"
        return board
```

Now I want to modify the board with X's and O's.
My input should be in the form of 1/2s. For example:

```
board.state = [[1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1]]
```

I want to transform every `1` to `"X"` & every `2` to `"O"` within the `__init__()` function. Is it possible or do you have any other suggestions? Like this:

```
board.state = [["X", "O", "X"], ["X", "O", "O"], ["O", "X", "X"]]
```

Right now what I run & my output:

```
board = Board()
board.state = [[1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1]]
print(board)

  1  |  2  |  1  
_____|_____|_____
     |     |     
  1  |  2  |  2  
_____|_____|_____
     |     |     
  2  |  1  |  1  
     |     |
```

Comment: " My input should be in the form of 1/2s." - Do you have a good reason for not using directly 'X' and 'O'?

Comment: Did you mean that you wanted to create a `Board` like this: `board = Board([[1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1]])`?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille
Player 1 should be by default "X" & Player 2 should be "O". That's why they are decoded as 1 & 2.

Comment: @quamrana
I created the empty board with the "Board" Class function already. But now I want to modify the board with `board.state = [[1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1]]`.
1's represent player 1, which should be printed as "X" & 2's represent player 2, which should be printed as "O"

Comment: Please do not delete questions that received an answer

Answer (score 1):

From your question its not clear to me what you want to do.
But if you want to `show your Board` in form of **'X' and 'O'** to player while keeping the **state** variable in form of **1 and 2**. you can easily do it using dictionary

```
def __str__(self):
    myDict = {1:'X', 2:'0'}
    board = "  %s  |  %s  |  %s  \n" %(myDict[self.state[0][0]], myDict[self.state[0][1]], myDict[self.state[0][2]])
    board += "_____|_____|_____\n"
    board += "     |     |     \n"
    board += "  %s  |  %s  |  %s  \n" % (myDict[self.state[1][0]], myDict[self.state[1][1]], myDict[self.state[1][2]])
    board += "_____|_____|_____\n"
    board += "     |     |     \n"
    board += "  %s  |  %s  |  %s  \n" % (myDict[self.state[2][0]], myDict[self.state[2][1]], myDict[self.state[2][2]])
    board += "     |     |     \n"
    return board
```